# Skeletonize an image

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I'm trying to skeletonize an image ([ref](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2458726?p_p_auth=FP7swv8r))

```
bin = Import["binary.png"]
skeleton = Pruning[Pruning@Thinning[bin], 15]
```

Input binary image:

[image]

Skeleton generated:

[image]

I'm not sure why the two thick edges at the left and right don't appear in the skeleton.
Could someone please have a look?

Comment: `Pruning[img] // Thinning` where `img` is your image?

Comment: or use the SkeletonTransform... Pruning[SkeletonTransform[img], 10]