# Generating a network from an image

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262834/skeletonize-an-image?noredirect=1#comment654545_262834)

I have to skeletonize an image ([ref](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2458726?p_p_auth=FP7swv8r)) and convert the skeleton into a network. I've tried the following

```
bin = Import["binary.png"]
skeleton = Pruning[SkeletonTransform[bin], 10]
graph = MorphologicalGraph[skeleton]
```

Input binary image:

[image]

Graph generated:
[image]

I'm not how to avoid the occurrence of the small edges circled in red.
Could someone please have a look?

Comment: Would it be ok to remove the small edges instead of avoiding them in the first place? E.g., by finding distances between vertices in the graph and using VertexContract to merge those that are closer than a distance you specify,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bin = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAZxM.png"];
g = MorphologicalGraph[bin]
```

[image]

```
vC = AssociationThread[VertexList[g], GraphEmbedding[g]];

edgesToContract[threshold_] := Select[EdgeList[g], 
  EuclideanDistance @@ (List @@ # /. vC) <= threshold &]

Graph[Fold[EdgeContract, g, edgesToContract[10]], 
 VertexSize -> .2, VertexLabels->Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 600, VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> vC[v]}]
```

[image]

The magic number `10` is obtained manually, using

```
Manipulate[Graph[Fold[EdgeContract, g, edgesToContract[distance]], 
    VertexSize -> Scaled[.01], ImageSize -> Large,
    PlotRange -> {.9, 1.1} MinMax @ # & /@ Transpose[GraphEmbedding[g]], 
    VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> vC[v]}], 
 {{distance, 1}, Range[1, 30], Manipulator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. The fifth line of code `Graph[Fold[EdgeContract, g, edgesToContract[10]]]` shows an error. Error: `A graph object is expected at position 1`. `GraphComputation`GraphContractDump`messageEdgeContract::inv: The argument 11\[UndirectedEdge]14 in EdgeContract[,11\[UndirectedEdge]14] is not a valid edges.`

Comment: @Natasha, the error message you are getting may be version/OS-related. The code and pictures I posted work without error both in version 11.3 (Windows) and in version 13.0 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: Hi, I am using version 12.0 (Windows)  Could you please have a look at the notebook file ([file](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/test.nb))?

Comment: @Natasha, I copied the contents of [file](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/test.nb) and pasted into a new notebook; evaluated the relevant lines and got the results in my answer without any errors. (You might want to start with a fresh kernel and copy the code above into a new notebook)

Comment: As you said, the issue might be due to the version that I am using (12.0). I face the same issue in a new notebook as well. Also, could you please explain how `Manipulate` function works; what happens when the `distance` scroll bar is adjucted

Comment: Do you get the same error message if you run `Fold[EdgeContract, g, edgesToContract[10]]`?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error message